# javascript div not expanding to match dynamic form fields

Tags: javascript, forms, expand

I have two divs that have been coded using javascript so that the "lightpole" div will expand to match the height of the "LayoutColumn2" div. It seems to be working fine everywhere except on the checkout page. This page has some dynamic form elements that expand once one section is completed. The lightpole div does not expand to match the expanded divs that container forms, even though they are within the larger LayoutColumn2 div.

Site: https://store-e262c.mybigcommerce.com/checkout.php?tk=eceb5394b7c03ae4a283b2eabff8f9f6

If that doesnt work add something to the cart>proceed to checkout>Select I'm a new Customer, Continue button. The lightpole break is visible near the footer and very apparent if you continue through the checkout process. I can delete users if someone wanted to create a test user.

```
<!--make lightPole expand to height of tallest column-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function(){
   var ht=($('#LayoutColumn2').height() > $('#LayoutColumn3').height()) ?
    $('#LayoutColumn2').height() : $('#LayoutColumn3').height(); $('#lightPole').height(ht); }); </script>
```

The html is lengthy and changes depending on the stage in the checkout process but I can still post it if someone wants it.

CSS

```
 #lightPole {
background:url(../images/lightPole8aSlice.png);
margin: 0 0 0 19.9px;
padding: 0;
position: absolute;
width: 15px;
z-index: -100;
 display: inline-block;
float: left;
} 

#LayoutColumn2{  
float: left;
height: auto;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 641px;
```

}

```
.Content {
background: url("../images/contentMiddleBackground.png") repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
float: left;
font-size: 0.95em;
margin: 0;
min-height: 266.5px;
padding: 0 5px 0 28px;
width: 609px;
```

}

It's nested pretty deeply and there are several other script blocks in there so maybe one of those is causing the problem...?

Comment: I can't post a picture as I'm still a newb to stackoverflow :(

Comment: But I can edit your post ;). Posted a solution, check if it wors. Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BQu9K/) for a live demo.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is imho to resize the `div`(`#lighPole`) when the other `div`(`#LayoutColumn2`) changes its height. This can be archived e.g. using the [jquery resize plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-resize-plugin/).

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/content/jquery.ba-resize.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $('#LayoutColumn2').resize(function() {
      var ht = Math.max($('#LayoutColumn2').height(), $('#LayoutColumn3').height());
      $('#lightPole').height(ht);
    }).resize();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: hhmm this seems to have made the lightpole only size to 200px   http://greenlight.mybigcommerce.com/categories/Beauty/    Do I need to add the clear float like in the jsfiddle example?

Comment: Nope it was me :) Here is what I have now with no luck       <script type="text/javascript" src="/content/jquery.ba-resize.min.js">
        $('#LayoutColumn2').resize(function() {
        var ht = Math.max($('#LayoutColumn2').height(), $('#LayoutColumn3').height());
        $('#lightPole').height(ht);
        });
    </script>    just to clarify, should I be using this in conjunction with the javascript code I provided early or just scrap that? Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @bjstone: Just scrap that code. Use my updated answer's code.

Comment: Well I was thinking about this and of course the lightpole wont expand! when the button is clicked the window is not reloading the page is just expanding. So if I could turn the code I started with into a function and have an onclick event that would call it again then it may expand! All good in theory but I have no idea how to write a function or onclick event :P